# PHP Version Conflict Error While install Composer in Windows7

Tags: error, magento2.3, php-7.1

I cannot able to install composer, PHP version conflict,

[image]

Comment: Try command like this,   /usr/bin/php7.1 /usr/local/bin/composer install

Comment: Solved. Removed the older version PHP path from Environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need edit this in Right click -> Tools -> Change PHP CLI Version

[image]